# what is the use of Snippets tab in Chrome Browser

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, debugging, google-chrome-devtools

What is the use of snippets tab while debugging in Chrome. I have seen some examples, but I was unable to understand their use.

See the image below for reference

[image: Snippet image]

Answer (score 1):

Use it to save commonly-used pieces ("snippets") of code that you can run at anytime. Helpful while debugging.

As an example, I use a lot of lodash in my code, and being able to debug lodash functions from the console with a saved `lodash.min.js` snippet is quite useful...

Comment: hai faisal is that possible to share step by step screen shots

Comment: DevTools tech writer here, I can confirm that this is exactly the purpose of Snippets!

Comment: okay thanks everyone , finally what i understood about snippet is,instead of writing pieces of codes every time in console while debugging,we can write the code in snippet (one time) and save that,we can run whenever we need